# Subtracting elements of vector in net

Tags: neural-networks

I'd like to implement the following function $f$ in a neural net:

$$
f(i,j)=s_i-s_j
$$

where $1\leq i,j\leq N$ are integers and the $s_i\in\mathbb{R}$ are learnable parameters.

What's the best way to do this?

`EmbeddingLayer[1, n, "Input" -> 2]` appears promising; it maps integers pair of integers $(i,j)$ to learnable real numbers $(s_i,s_j)$. However, I haven't figured out how to subtract them afterwards.

#### Attempt 1

I tried this:

```
NetChain[{
  EmbeddingLayer[1, n, "Input" -> 2],
  ThreadingLayer[Subtract]
  }]
```

which fails with

```
NetChain::ninctyp2: Incompatible types for output of layer 1, EmbeddingLayer[1,\[Ellipsis]], and input to layer 2, ThreadingLayer[Subtract,\[Ellipsis]]; a 2*1 matrix is not compatible with a pair of tensors, respectively.
```

It fails because the `ThreadingLayer` expects two scalar inputs, not one input that's a 2-vector, but am not sure how to massage the data into the right form.

#### Attempt 2

This appears to work, but seems hokey:

```
NetGraph[{
  EmbeddingLayer[1, n, "Input" -> 2],
  PartLayer[1],
  PartLayer[2],
  ThreadingLayer[Subtract]
  },
 {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, {2, 3} -> 4}]
```

[image]

It sends the first layer output in two directions, pulls out the first and second elements, and recombines them later. I feel like there's got to be a simpler way than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $s_i-s_j$ is essentially a dot product with the vector `{1,-1}`, you could use:

```
net = NetGraph[
  {
    ConstantArrayLayer["Array" -> {{1, -1}}],
    EmbeddingLayer[1, n, "Input" -> 2],
    DotLayer[]
  }, {1 -> 3, 2 -> 3}]
```

[image]